# Microsoft Power Automate Switch case

Tags: switch-statement, power-automate

So what I'm trying to replicate is the following,

```
   string str = GetInput from Form();

   switch (str)
   {
      case "1":
      case "1 week":
          assign variable = 1
          Insert variable to excel column
          break;
      case "2":
      case "2 weeks":
          assign variable = 3
          Insert variable to excel column
      case "4":
      case "4 weeks":
          assign variable = 4
          Insert variable to excel column
      default:
          assign variable = 0
          Insert variable to excel column
          break;
  }
```

Currently, my flow is similar to the following diagram

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5sbq.png)

1. When a new response is submitted
2. Get response details
3. Create item action (Run the above switch case condition using a power automate -
   functions)

Answer (score 1):

You are using an `Apply for Each` control in your flow which is equivalent to a `For` loop in normal programming language. You need to use `Switch` control for your problem as shown in image below. I have used a sample string parameter to show the usage of switch statement, but if your data is coming from an array you can apply `Switch` inside `Apply for Each` loop.

[Read this article](https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/d365demystified/posts/switch-case-in-a-flow-power-automate) for step by step guide.

[image]